# Tkinter button stays pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am making a tkinter code that uses button widget but when I press the button, it stays pushed until the function which is executed on button press is not completed. I want the button to be released immediately and execute the function.
Here is a code that shows a good example of the happening:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100') # size/position of root
def callback(): # this function will run on button press
    print('Firing in 3')
    time.sleep(3) # wait for 3 seconds
def main(): #function 'main'
    b = Button(root, text="ᖴIᖇE", width=10,height=2, command=callback)# setting the button
    b["background"] = 'red' #button color will be red
    b["activebackground"] = 'yellow'  #button color will be yellow for the time when the button will not be released
    b.place(x=25,y=25) #placing the button
main() # using function 'main'
mainloop()
```

Comment: you should use threads.

Comment: Button being stuck depends on the code. If you actually have sleep, you should use multithreading or `after` instead. If the actual process takes that long, you could use update method(s) or multi-threading.

Comment: Well, you told it to sleep, so it's sleeping. It  can't update the display when its sleeping.

Comment: Multithreading _is not_ the answer. Please.

Comment: @BryanOakley I accept your information but in the main code which I am using , I am using loops and saving some images using PIL module and this also causes the same problem.

Comment: tkinter is single threaded -- it can only do one thing at a time. while your loop is running, it can't update the display. There are _many_ questions about this on stackoverflow.

Comment: When it comes to Tkinter do not use `sleep`. The `after` method is what you would use here. This goes for anything that requires a timed delay in tkinter.

Comment: @jsbueno Do you just mean that it should be a fallback option?

Comment: I mean it is not what one wants. If the actual calculations are CPU bound , and would gain advantage of being run in a separate core, one could arrange to use multiprocessing. Multithreading will just complicate things by not colaborating with the GUI library, and gain nothing.

Comment: But most commenters here were just throwing "multithread" at this problem, when the answer is to go asynchronous, in a way that is collaborative with the GUI framework.

Comment: you can disable it after your possess:

def switch():
    #your commands
    b1["state"] = "disabled" 
b2 = Button(text="test", command=switch)

Answer (score 3):

GUI programs are typically driven in a single thread, which is controlled by the "main loop" of the graphic toolkit in use. That is: a program usually set up the application, and pass the control to the toolkit, which runs a tight loop that answers all users (and network, file, etc...) events, and the only user code ever to run again are the callbacks coded during the setup phase.

At the same time, when your code is running in during a callback, it holds controls - which means the toolkit won't be able to answer to any events while your function does not return.

What has to be done is to write code that cooperates with the GUI toolkit - that is, create events that generate further callbacks, if you need things spaced in time. In the case of tkinter, this is achieved with the method `.after` of a widget: after that many milliseconds, the callable passed will be run.  `time.sleep`, on the other hand, stops the single thread there, and the event loop does not run.

In your example, you can simply write:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100') # size/position of root

def callback(): # this function will run on button press
    print('Firing in 3')
    root.after(3000, realcallback)

def realcallback():
    print('Firing now!')

def main(): #function 'main'
    b = Button(root, text="ᖴIᖇE", width=10,height=2, command=callback)# setting the button
    b["background"] = 'red' #button color will be red
    b["activebackground"] = 'yellow'  #button color will be yellow for the time when the button will not be released
    b.place(x=25,y=25) #placing the button
main() # using function 'main'
mainloop()
```

Comment: And what when I use loops that take time in the callback function?

Comment: if your loops take time _calculating_ stuff then you could resort to threading. But if the "time" is to animate game objects, which seens to be the case: each game object should jsut be drawn "instantly" in a position and schedule a `.after` callback to be rendered in its next position. USing classes for game objects make that quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `threading` inside the function you're being blocked while pressed. This is my edit on yours:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading

root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100')  # size/position of root


def callback():  # this function will run on button press
    def callback2():
        print('Firing in 3')
        time.sleep(3)  # wait for 3 seconds
    threading.Thread(target=callback2).start()


def realcallback():
    print('Firing now')


def main():  # function 'main'
    b = Button(
        root,
        text="Fire",
        width=10,
        height=2,
        command=callback
    )  # setting the button
    b["background"] = 'red'  # button color will be red
    # button color will be yellow for the time when the button will not be released
    b["activebackground"] = 'yellow'
    b.place(x=25, y=25)  # placing the button


main()  # using function 'main'
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100+100+100') # size/position of root

def callback(): # this function will run on button press
    root.update() #<- this works for me..
    print('Firing in 3')
    root.after(3000, realcallback)

def realcallback():
    print('Firing now!')

def main(): #function 'main'
    b = Button(root, text="ᖴIᖇE", width=10,height=2, command=callback)# setting the  button
    b["background"] = 'red' #button color will be red
    b["activebackground"] = 'yellow'  #button color will be yellow for the time when the button will not be released
    b.place(x=25,y=25) #placing the button
main() # using function 'main'
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution! Your answer could use a little polish, though. I'd suggest trying to explain in the text part what the code sample is doing and why. Also, I doubt that what your code does is what OP was after: OP was looking for a way to run a lengthier computation without blocking tkinter's UI thread, I think.